# Converting Strings in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to convert my string value to int16 and only show 2 decimal places.  I have tried the below, but it throws an error as my string value is not actually converted?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number1 = "1234.00011";
        Console.Write(number1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        string r = String.Format("{0:F2}", number1);
        Console.Write(Convert.ToInt16(r));
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT
The line that throws the error is

```
Console.Write(Convert.ToInt16(r));
```

And the error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: An integer won't have any decimal places. What exception is being thrown, and on what line, exactly?

Comment: @MikeHofer see my edit for further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `string.Format` is using a floating point format specifier and providing a string argument. These are mutually incompatible. As a result, the string argument is inserted as-is into the result, and stored in `r`, so that you don't get the desired two-digit rounding you're looking for.

What you likely want to do is something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number1 = "1234.00011";
        Console.Write(number1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        var r1 = float.Parse(number1);
        string r = String.Format("{0:F2}", r1);
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.Write((int)r1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In my tests, it produces the following output:

```
1234.00011
1234.00
1234
```

Note that the second line has the desired rounding, because we provided a floating point value to `string.Format`, so that `{0:F2}` would work properly. The third line has no decimal places, because we used a direct cast and includes no floating point digits whatsoever.